# Admin - Add new post - hook to display some custom input fields

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

- i have a custom post type
- this post type needs some fields to be inserted into a custom MySQL table (wp_my_custom_table) where i store some relations IDs with other products and a  number to sort them
- i don't know how to put these input fields them after the textarea. I know how to insert them at "save_post" action hook.
- these are not registered as "custom fields", are just a few input fields needed for each post type like this
  [image]
  The  tag doesn't work, so i put the code that i have tried as image:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found, there is a hook "edit_form_after_editor".